# Rails have not created test directory for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I have created a new application of Ruby on Rails. I use RubyMine and created the project using New Project->RailsApps Sample->rails-devise-pundit
I have created models and controllers, but just realized I do not have any test directory under my root path.
For example, I have a Transaction model and when I do:

```
rails g resource Post --skip --no-resource-route --no-migration --no-helper --no-assets
```

I get this:

```
  invoke  active_record
  skip    app/models/transaction.rb
  invoke    rspec
  identical      spec/models/transaction_spec.rb
  invoke      factory_girl
  identical        spec/factories/transactions.rb
  invoke  controller
  skip    app/controllers/transactions_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  exist      app/views/transactions
  invoke    rspec
```

See, there is no test directory at all here
How can I auto generate test directories with resources for all of my models and controllers? (As I see a guide for testing in Ruby here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Comment: It seems that the `rails-devise-pundit` application template doesn't have any test folders initialized, have you tried to manually had a `test` folder with `test/test_helper.rb`(as it is when creating a blank rails application)  in it and regenerate your ressource ?

Comment: I have created a test directory with an empty file test_helper.rb, and then re-ran my rails g resource command, but did not work.

Comment: `rails-devise-pundit`application template has a customized generator script (see in config/application.rb) that's why the 'rails g resource...' command doesn't behave as a blank Rails app. Update the `config.generators`block in the file to adapt control which files are automatically generated.

Comment: Yes you do. The directory is called `spec` and is for `rspec`-style tests.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I just realized the line:
g.test_framework :rspec,
        fixtures: true,
        view_specs: false,
        helper_specs: false,
        routing_specs: false,
        controller_specs: false,
        request_specs: false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
so I can test under rspec framework